# Simple data transfer within viewcontroller without transition

Tags: swift, xcode, delegates, protocols

So i am new to app development and i am trying to set up a very simple delegation/protocol pattern. I have been searching and trying different tutorials but can't seem to find anything that works and am getting in such a muddle. Please can somebody help. I will break i down so that its really clear as to what i need -

I have two view controllers, '**DetailedVC**' and '**SelectionsVC**'.

*DetailedVC has a variable* called -

```
var sendingData = (choice: "", choiceValue:0.0)
```

and

```
UIbutton buttonSelectTapped
```

*SelectionsVC has a variable* called -

```
var recievedData = (choice: "", choiceValue:0.0)
```

And all i want to do is send the data from the variable '*sendingData*' in DetailedVC when the button (buttonSelectTapped) is tapped to the SelectionsVC and store it in the variable '*recievedData*'. I do not want the VC to transition from one to the other or anything to be sent back, only to send the data to the other VC. 
Then when the user views that controller 'SelectionsVC' at whatever stage, the data will be called in the viewDidLoad when loading that controller.

Comment: I don't get it... Is SelectionsVC instantiated somewhere?

Comment: @V.Roberts how are to presenting SelectionsVC?

Comment: Yes the SelectionsVC can be viewed by a tab bar at bottom of the app

Comment: i mean how r you calling SelectionsVC screen?

Comment: like presentViewController or else??

Comment: I don't want to present the SelectionsVC. I am using an alert to let the user know their selection has been added to their selections list, then they can continue on with their choices. They can then take a look at all selections made once they have completed everything by using tab bar icon at bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NSUserDefault to pass data between viewcontroller if you do not want the VC to *transition* from one to the other or anything to be sent back, only to send the data to the other VC.

**DetailedVC Code**

```
    func viewDidLoad() {
   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("selectedData")
    }

    func didTapButtonSelectTapped() {
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(sendingData , forKey: "selectedData")
    }
```

**SelectionsVC code**

```
func viewDidLoad() {
  if(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("selectedData")) {
    recievedData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("selectedData")
   }
}
```

**But as your question title describe their is no use of protocol/delegate in above code.**

Passing Data on transition from viewcontroller :

**DetailedVC Code**

```
func didTapButtonSelectTapped() {
let vc = SelectionsVC()
vc.recievedData = sendingData
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did post a question on what is the best way to do this and i was told either delegates/protocols or global variables but there is a lot of bad press on global variables so i tried delegation. I will try your above suggestion

Comment: @V.Roberts there may be other best solution, you can choose as per requirement! let may know your response.

Comment: @V.Roberts did you get your solution??

Comment: I got two errors on both controllers. In DetailedVC error on this line  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(self.sendingData, forKey: "selectedData") error - cannot convert value type (choice: String, choiceValue:Double) to expected argument type anyObject and the same for SelectionsVC

Comment: @V.Roberts so use setDouble(value: Double, forKey defaultName: String), doubleForKey(defaultName: String) -> Double

Comment: @V.Roberts I have edited answer, please check & reply!

Comment: Ok so i have this for the buttonTapped function of detailedVC   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(self.sendingData.choiceValue, forKey: "double")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(self.sendingData.choice, forKey: "string")
But can't get rid of errors on selectionsVC just trying to work through them.